# Not getting Pubnub payload in bundle from Notification tray. When app is killed

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, pubnub

I have integrated pubnub API in one of my project. I am trying to get bundle of data that i have sent in payload. I have added FCM for push notification. I am getting push notification in all cases but not getting bundle data when app is killed or in background. Already getting payload object when app is in foreground but not getting any data when app is in background or killed.

Payload 1 :

```
{
   "pn_gcm": {
   "notification": {
   "title": "Barack Obama",
   "body": "12",
   "channelName": "Hell 4_656"
   }
 },
"firstName": "Barack",
"lastName": "Obama",
"displayName": "Barack Obama",
"profileImageUrl": "abcURL",
"userId": "173",
"type": "sender",
"time": "1615958943297",
"message": "12"
}
```

PayLoad 2 :

```
{
pn_gcm={
  notification={
  title=BarackObama,
  body=Hello,
  image=Hell4_656
  }
  },
  firstName=Barack,
  lastName=Obama,
  displayName=BarackObama,
  time=1615958740553,
  type=sender,
  message=Hello,
  profileImageUrl=abcURL,
  userId=173
}
```

I am getting notification object when app is in foreground but not getting any of them when app is in background or killed.(Getting some FCM default object)

**I am trying to get notification object in bundle when launch app from Notification tray**

**Answer**
Made JSON payload like this :

```
  {
"pn_gcm": {
  "notification": {
    "title": "Barack Obama",
    "body": "18"
  },
  "body": {
    "channelName": "Hell 5_657",
    "firstName": "Barack",
    "lastName": "Obama",
    "displayName": "Barack Obama",
    "profileImageUrl": 
    "http://3.137.127.137/quiqle/uploads/profile/1615523786_4866.jpg",
    "userId": "173",
    "type": "sender",
    "time": "1615965488916",
    "message": "18"
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `data` with information which you want to receive with push into `pn_gcm`.
Information outside of `pn_(gcm|apns)` (including tjpse) will be delivered as regular messages

Message can be as follows:

using `notification`:

```js
{
   "pn_gcm":{
      "notification":{
         "title":"Chat invitation",
         "body":"John invited you to chat",
         "sound":"default"
      }
   }
}
```

Or using `data`:

```js
{
  "pn_gcm" : {
    "data" : {
      "room" : "Portugal vs Denmark",
      "body" : "great match!"
    }
  }
}
```

or both:

```js
{
  "pn_gcm" : {
    "notification": {
      "title":"Portugal vs Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    },
    "data" : {
      "room" : "Portugal vs Denmark",
      "body" : "great match!"
    }
  }
}
```

For an explanation on the different between `data` and `notification`, please read the official FCM docs, [About FCM messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

See also:
[Why are my FCM push notifications not working?](https://support.pubnub.com/hc/en-us/articles/360051495472-Why-are-my-FCM-push-notifications-not-working-)

Comment: can you elaborate your answer ?

Comment: I have added data object to json File but not getting it in Bundle.

Comment: Yes i am getting data after adding data object. Thanks!!

Comment: It will work with just `notification`. Just be sure to read the FCM docs link I added. `notification types should display by default by the Android OS, where as `data` requires you to implement a method to receive the message and your code does the display. At least that is how I remember it when I last read those docs.